# Is there a reason why the python 3.x insert function behaves differently from other list functions when it comes to indexing with minus one

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to understand why the index of minus one behaves as it does with the built-in insert function.

```
# assinging a list to variable a.
a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
print(a) # we get [1, 2, 3, 4]
a.insert(-1, 5)
print(a) # we get [1, 2, 3, 5, 4]
# why is this different than other list indexing using minus one.
```

Comment: Just like when you insert at any other index, the item that used to be at that index, and all items after it (if any) get moved over to the right. Before insertion, index `-1` is equivalent to index `3`. You insert a `5` at index `3`, and the `4` that used to occupy that index gets moved to the right.

Comment: @Paul M.  Yep thanks, I get it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not, actually. In case you use

```py
>>> a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> a[-1]
4
```

The [-1] index gives you the last element. All is fine. So why the -1 in insert() function inserts the element **before** the element, and not as the last? Answer is in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html):

> Insert an item at a given position. The first argument is the index of the element **before which to insert**, so a.insert(0, x) inserts at the front of the list, and a.insert(len(a), x) is equivalent to a.append(x).

So as you see, it might be counterintuitive, but it's all in the docs. As a sidenote, I'd recommend you reading [wtfpython](https://github.com/satwikkansal/wtfpython), maybe you'll find some other fancy quirks.